# Same video opening in videoModal

Tags: php, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I have six links to mp4 videos held on my server and want each link to open up a videoModal pop up window and play the video. The same video plays from each link. What have I done wrong?

Example link 1

```
<a href="#videoModal" class="gallery-box video" data-toggle="modal"  data-video="mp4/totalise.mp4" data-target="#videoModal">
    <img src="img/totalise.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 1">
        <div class="gallery-box-caption">
            <div class="gallery-box-content"> 
                Totalise : Sound of Flak
            </div>
        </div>
</a>
```

Example link 2

```
<a href="#videoModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-video="mp4/gyibbk.mp4" data-target="#videoModal">
                    <img src="img/gyibbk.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 1">
                    <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                        <div class="gallery-box-content"> 
                                gyibbk (edit) : Solo project 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
```

I have four more like this just changing the url for the video file and title. 
And then the following code is used once

```
<div id="videoModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the js

```
$(function() {
$(".video").click(function () {
  var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
  videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
  videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
  $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
  $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
  });
});
```

});